# why does my code if elif else apply to all?

Tags: python

can I have solution for this
let say, I have this

`df['Location']`
*run
and i got this

```
0           New York, NY
1          Chantilly, VA
2             Boston, MA
3             Newton, MA
4           New York, NY
             ...        
667         Fort Lee, NJ
668    San Francisco, CA
669        Irwindale, CA
670    San Francisco, CA
671         New York, NY
Name: Location, Length: 659, dtype: object

then I want to make it simplified by if it contain Nwe York, NY then I want it become NY. If it contain Boston, MA then I want it become MA. Etc

so I write this code

def clean_location_1(x):
    if 'CA':
        return 'CA'
    elif 'NY':
        return 'NY'
    elif 'DC':
        return 'DC'
    elif 'MA':
        return 'MA'
    elif 'IL':
        return 'IL'
    elif 'VA':
        return 'VA'
    else:
        return 'others'


df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(clean_location_1)

but, when I run my script, all the Location become CA

how can I solve this?
```

Comment: What do you think `if 'CA'` actually does? hint, it's not the same as `if x == 'CA'`, which is probably what you are looking for. You also don't actually call this function from the `apply`, `apply(lambda x: clean_location_1(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions of solving this using your approach is the following.
import pandas as pd

```
data = pd.DataFrame([{'location': 'New York, NY'},
                     {'location': 'Chantilly, VA'},
                     {'location': 'Boston, MA'},
                     {'location': 'Newton, MA'},
                     {'location': 'San Francisco, CA'}])

def clean_location_1(x):
    if 'CA' in x:
        return 'CA'
    elif 'NY' in x:
        return 'NY'
    elif 'DC' in x:
        return 'DC'
    elif 'MA' in x:
        return 'MA'
    elif 'IL' in x:
        return 'IL'
    elif 'VA' in x:
        return 'VA'
    else:
        return 'others'

data['location'].apply(clean_location_1)
```

Your problem was incorrect condition in the if/else block.

Another way of doing this might be.

```
list_states = ['CA', 'NY', 'DC', 'MA', 'IL', 'VA']
data['location'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1] if x.split(' ')[-1] in list_states else 'others')
```

Then you won't need a huge if/else block.

Comment: You aren't returning `others` if they are not there, in second approach, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518667/why-does-my-code-if-elif-else-apply-to-all/68518712#68518712)

Comment: You're right, I've changed my answer a bit.

Comment: While making `DataFrame` you don't have to do that. You can make `DataFrame` like this: `pd.DataFrame({'location':['New York, NY',....,'San Francisco, CA']})` it is easier and simple to write.

Comment: Sure, but I like to separate rows when filling a `DataFrame`, it makes code more readable when there are multiple columns in a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `if 'CA'` it doesn't mean much, you have to check the value.

This should do it using `pd.Series.str.contains`:

```
def clean_location_1(x):
    if x.str.contains('CA'):
        return 'CA'
    elif x.str.contains('NY'):
        return 'NY'
    elif x.str.contains('DC'):
        return 'DC'
    elif x.str.contains('MA'):
        return 'MA'
    elif x.str.contains('IL'):
        return 'IL'
    elif x.str.contains('VA'):
        return 'VA'
    else:
        return 'others'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple. You are not comparing the string with x. And 'CA' will always return true as non empty strings are truthy. That is why everything changes to CA

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
if "<str>":
```

always returns `True` and that means in your code, it will always return `CA`. So, you can try this, check if `x` is in `<word>` or not.

```
def clean_location_1(x):
    if 'CA' in x:
        return 'CA'
    elif 'NY' in x:
        return 'NY'
    elif 'DC' in x:
        return 'DC'
    elif 'MA' in x:
        return 'MA'
    elif 'IL' in x:
        return 'IL'
    elif 'VA' in x:
        return 'VA'
    else:
        return 'others'
df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(clean_location_1)
```

Or you can try this, which is easy, clean and simple:

```
check=["CA","NY","DC","MA","IL","VA"]
def clean_location_1(x):
    y=x.rsplit(", ",1)[1]
    if y in check:
        return y
    else:
        return "others"

df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(clean_location_1)
```

Here we are creating the `list of short form` of locations, as you did in every `if-else` statements and storing that in `check` and checking that if `x` has `values` of `check` or not.

Or one-liner solution, same as second approach but in one line:

```
check=["CA","NY","DC","MA","IL","VA"]
df['Location'] = df['Location'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(", ",1)[1] if x.rsplit(", ",1)[1] in check else "others")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
states = ['CA', 'NY', 'DC', 'MA', 'IL', 'VA']
df['State'] = df['Location'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1] \
                             .rename('State').to_frame().query('State in @states')
df['State'] = df['State'].fillna('other')
```

```
>>> df
            Location  State
0       New York, NY     NY
1      Chantilly, VA     VA
2         Boston, MA     MA
3         Newton, MA     MA
4       New York, NY     NY
5       Fort Lee, NJ  other
6  San Francisco, CA     CA
7      Irwindale, CA     CA
8  San Francisco, CA     CA
9       New York, NY     NY
```